# Writing a GUI for a Forth application

Tags: user-interface, forth

I was asked by a friend to write a **simple** **GUI** containing some charts and selections of common commands for an application he wrote in Forth. However, I have basically zero knowledge about **Forth**, only that you can't write a GUI in this language (at least that's what he told me).

Now I've been wondering what other programming languages you would suggest which do interact well with Forth and provide libraries (e.g. Java Swing) for interface programming?

*Note:* I'm still a beginner in programming, and my experiences so far are limited to Java, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and some C#.

Comment: What do you mean by *"you can't write a GUI in this language"*? For instance, there is [bigFORTH](http://bigforth.sourceforge.net/): "The most striking feature is the graphical user interface MINOS (GUI in Forth) ... Extensive libraries: ... graphical user interface (MINOS GUI)"

Comment: @abrjak01, could you please mention, what the platform (operating system, Forth system) do you use?

Comment: @ruvim, to be honest, I don't really know yet, because my friend has built a machine for chemsitral Analysis himself (Project for his master degree in Chemistry) and he uses Forth to "tell the machine what to do". Specifications will follow, I just went ahead and went looking for some General hints to solve this since I have Zero Experience with this.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, as I said, I have Zero experience with Forth and only repeat what I was told, but thanks for the Link, I will look through it.

Comment: What OS did you want to use?

Answer (score 2):

[Win32Forth](http://win32forth.sourceforge.net) comes with complete Windows GUI and words to use all `user32.dll` and `gdi32.dll` functions. It also has a great development environment and windows form creator and editor. Very easy to create user interfaces with it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest XHTML and Co. (i.e. CSS, JavaScript, XSLT, HTTP) to create user interface (GUI) and interact with Forth. In most general case you include an http-server into Forth system. In some special cases a Web browser object can be embedded into Forth application (for example, using COM on Windows).
Also on Windows you can use [HTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) (HTML Application) — quite simple solution. HTA can be started from Forth as well as Forth from HTA.

Another way is to use Qt framework (some Forth systems can have bindings).

Yet another way — just use API to underlying system (like user32.dll and gdi32.dll on Windows). Some Forth systems contain GUI-libraries that are based on underlying system API.

Also as edge case, user interface can be implemented in any language as shared library or as separate process with IPC (inter process communication) to Forth system.

In any case, usually GUI is created using special languages, libraries or APIs. GUI is not a subject of Forth as general-purpose programming language.

Comment: thanks for the great suggestions! I will look through them and try to work with them.

Comment: I have successful experience in developing app with Forth core (SP-Forth) and Html+JS GUI with NWJS. I used web-sockets for connecting forth core and NWJS.

Answer (score 1):

Bernd Paysan's MINOS may be a way to write GUI code in Forth:
https://bernd-paysan.de/theseus/minos-1.html

Answer (score 1):

SP-Forth allow developing applications with GUI and library WinLib: http://spf.sourceforge.net/ UI libs: http://spf.sourceforge.net/docs/devel.en.html#ui

Answer (score 1):

Adding a GUI to a program written in Forth is no different from the same problem in any language. You either have to write graphic code yourself or be able to call graphic libraries. In both cases on e.g. MS-windows you have to call functions present in DLL's and you need the documentation of those functions. Most serious Forth's allow to call DLL's. Of course libraries that are internal to a different language are less easily used, but why would you want to? You then commit to that language and are better off using that language from the get-go.

Forth being an interpreter you can couple a plot program  easily via a pipe, but that is a one way street. It may be viable if the plot program has the  interaction ( such as enlarge, change scale, crop, print etc.) you need.