# how to write a GUI for gforth

Tags: user-interface, gtk, forth, gforth

I would like to learn GUI for linux gforth but documentation about that are , _from my point of view _ ,awful obsolete or both :) to be honest.

I already searched & tried many from all of https://www.reddit.com/r/Forth/comments/ypo3kd/what_is_the_best_way_to_make_lightwheight_guis_in/ but this didn't help.

I tried FFL/GTK solution https://github.com/irdvo/ffl/issues/10 for linux gforth GUI but FFL is no more maintained by his author he mentioned on his GitHub . So examples are a mess buggy-no more compatible and so on so I cannot learn from there.

I also tried to read from Minos tutorial provided by gforth package but this is not a tutorial at all just examples that do not really work in facts ... cannot exit from any of them for example Documentation about it is so empty I just cannot use it https://gforth.org/manual/MINOS2.html

PS: currently I use a TK use but that calls shell that itself calls TK for more or less each interaction this cannot be a solution for bigger applications that the example given as picture (even this one is working fine)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mA7MhjGiIiWimQ7rheeNQgockJ8vK_Dw/view?usp=sharing example pic is here

it is currently

```
\ needs to have tcl/tk wish installed
0 value tk-in
0 value tk-out
variable #clicks
0 #clicks !
: wish{ \ send command to wish
    tk-in to outfile-id 
;
: add-one 
    1 #clicks +! 
;   \ get an action as example here counting clicks 
: cleaning
    tk-in close-file tk-out close-file s" rm /dev/shm/tk-in /dev/shm/tk-out " system \ clear temprary files for a clean code
    cr 0 (bye)
;
: }wish \ finish command to wish
    tk-in flush-file throw stdout to outfile-id 
; 
: update-wish wish{ .\" .label configure -text \"clicks: " #clicks @ . .\" \"" cr }wish ;   \ redraw window 
: counting
    begin
        tk-out key-file
        dup 'q' = if 
            wish{ ." exit" }wish
            cleaning
        then    \ quit wish 
        dup '+' = if 
            add-one update-wish 
        then    \ add one if '+' received
        #clicks @ 5 > if
            wish{ ." exit" }wish    \ exit on 5 clicks 
            cleaning
        then
    4 = until 
;           
: initiating
    s" mkfifo /dev/shm/tk-in /dev/shm/tk-out" system    \ create temporary files here new version mignt use a memory block as file
    s" wish </dev/shm/tk-in >/dev/shm/tk-out &" system  \ manage how they are used input/output to the external interpreter
    s" /dev/shm/tk-in" w/o open-file throw to tk-in \ only input has to be writable
    s" /dev/shm/tk-out" r/o open-file throw to tk-out   \ so output is read only to get performances (how cares on modern PCs)
    wish{
        .\" wm protocol . WM_DELETE_WINDOW { puts 'q' } " cr    
        .\" wm title . \"forth count\"" cr
        .\" wm geometry . \"200x100+100+100\"" cr
        .\" label  .label -text \"There have been no clicks yet\" " cr
        .\" button .click -text \"click me\" -command \" puts '+' \" " cr 
        .\" button .exit -text \"EXIT\" -command \" puts 'q' \" " cr
        ." pack .label .click .exit" cr 
    }wish                   \ TK window management
;
: checkrunispossible 
    s" which wish 1> /dev/null" system  \ system bash exexute
    $? 0 > if               \ if TK wish tool is not installed quit
        cr 27 emit .\" [31;1m TCL-TK wish command must be installed." 
        27 emit .\" [0m" cr 0 (bye)
    then
;
: main
    checkrunispossible  initiating  counting    cleaning
;
main
```

this is dirty solution and will be incredibly low performances solution if I write a bigger application because of the system calls & TCL/TK itself too..

It really seem to be a lake a documentations here I know forth is no more used as GUI application since 80's but it was so why not make my hobbyist scripts in gforth having GUI.

I m not currently interested in using another forth interpreter.

Does any have a real tutorial from a very very basic "application" like a few buttons one that is really documented and not just be given as-is  to provide ? *maybe with gtk or minos ?*

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at a more general question: [Writing a GUI for a Forth application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416466/writing-a-gui-for-a-forth-application).

A promising way is to write (or generate) GUI in HTML and control it from Forth.

Use [NW.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js#node-webkit-is-renamed-nwjs)/HTML for GUI and communicate it via WebSockets from Gforth, or use a web-server in Gforth (see an outdated [example](https://github.com/harrypower/gforth_webserver), and [another one](https://bitbucket.org/demonview/forth-httpd/src/master/)) and control it via WebSockets too or plain HTTP, or use [Gforth in SCGI](https://github.com/flagxor/flagxor.com/blob/master/dynamic/scgi.fs).

A more hard way is to use Qt library. Try to create bindings using [SWIG in Gforth](https://gforth.org/manual/Automated-interface-generation-using-SWIG.html).

If you want to dive deeper, you might find the library [QtE5](https://github.com/MGWL/QtE5) useful, which is a Qt wrapper for easier access from other languages (such as Forth and D).

Comment: WebUI is not GUI :) thanks for the try -- SWIG migth be a solution I will chek it too (_the first link I found it already to be true_)

Comment: Take a look at the [QtE5](https://github.com/MGWL/QtE5) library as an adapter/proxy for accessing Qt from Forth (post updated).